# Is radius of convergence of power series of the function unique?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I have function $f(x)=\frac{1}{3-z}$ which can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-(z-2)} \quad \text{or}\quad \frac{1}{3(1-\frac{z}{3})}
\end{align}
By the $\frac{1}{1-r}=1+r+r^2+... $  and $|r|<1$, their Taylor expansion

$\frac{1}{1-(z-2)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (z-2)^n$ and the radius of convergence $R=1$.

$\frac{1}{3(1-\frac{z}{3})}=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{z}{3}\right)^n$ and radius of convergence $R=3$.

It seems it is not unique. Can we say that ?

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The expansions are not around the same point. Thus, we do not expect the convergence radius be the same

Comment: *What* depends on *where*: the center determines the radius.

Comment: There aren't the same power series, so it's not surprising that they have different radii of convergence.